# HTML jquery Only render visible rows in table

Tags: jquery, html

The plugin "DataTables" is a very good example of what I need. In DataTables its called "scroller" and renders only the needed data in the table but I got some bugs with that plugin and cant use it.

Are there other plugins with the same Feature like that?
I need to display tables with 100k rows and don't want to wait minutes to load.

Comment: Please make some effort and provide your code

Comment: I got the same bug like this issue: [https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/371](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/371)

Comment: Maybe you haven't read about AJAX? https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax It will not load all 100k rows at once, it will only load if you decided to use search or clicked another page.

Comment: Additional link I think that will help: https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html

Comment: But I Need the table on one site and should be a Client-side data source